# Transform a vector to run to its max value without decreasing

Tags: r

I am looking for a clever way to transform a vector into a version of itself which runs to its maximum value without ever decreasing, and which plateaus once it reaches its maximum.

So, for input like:

```
x <- c(1,2,6,3,2,9,8,4)
```

I'd like output like:

```
y <- c(1,2,6,6,6,9,9,9)
```

I find this easy to do with a loop, but I am trying to do this to 1000's of reasonably large vectors, so I'd really prefer a more efficient solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cummax` to do this

```
cummax(x)
#[1] 1 2 6 6 6 9 9 9
```